# What was wrong with my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons, voting

First consider this question

1. [C# find a number common to two or more lists [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102482/c-sharp-find-a-number-common-to-two-or-more-lists/30102629)

A simple but ambiguous question that a few high reputation users answered but in the end turned out to be a duplicate.

Then consider a second question

2. [The union of the intersects of the 2 set combinations of a sequence of sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104453/the-union-of-the-intersects-of-the-2-set-combinations-of-a-sequence-of-sequences)

A well specified, unambiguous question that, I don't think, is a duplicate. **Admittedly this question is a "straw man".** This question did not originally contain an attempt from the OP (me).

---

The contrast between these two questions has left me a little bemused. <s>What is the purpose of Stack Overflow? There seems to be a disjoint here, a good way of getting reputation is to answer ambiguous questions as if they are duplicates. A bad way of getting reputation as asking, what I think is a, clear question that is not a duplicate.</s>

Is it important to show a failed attempt when asking a question? Should I immediately down vote questions that don't?

Comment: If you feel that ambiguous and/or duplicate questions shouldn't be answered or, if answered, they shouldn't be rewarded, then why did you answer the question that you linked to?

Comment: Comparing voting on Qs vs As is a bit of a apples-oranges thing to start with.  Currently, both Qs have a negative net value.  I am not sure that UVs on answers which provide a decent solution is an indicator of a voting problem.

Comment: Oh.. SO voting:(   I thought you were referring to the general election curently taking place in the UK.  I was going to answer 'move all polling stations into bars'.

Comment: @Servy, I didn't think it was a duplicate, I misunderstood the question and thought he was asking a different question, like the second I posted. When it turned out the OP was asking  a duplicate it got me thinking, what is the best answer to my interpretation of the question.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the problem people might have had with your question was the way it was phrased. Your question stated:

> I want to find the set of items that occur in 2 or more sequences in a sequence of sequences.
>
> ...
>
> So, given the signature,
>
> ...
>
> please provide the body.
>
> ...
>
> The accepted answer will be, in my opinion, the best combination of readability and potential performance.

That sounds an awful lot like a work request, which rubs people the wrong way here.

Maybe if you reworded that to read less like a specification and more like a question, it would be received better.

Comment: Thank you, I've taken your answer on board and reworded this question and will use the guidance for future questions.

Comment: Seems your advice worked, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118863/the-union-of-the-intersects-of-the-2-set-combinations-of-a-sequence-of-sequences/30119673